# Bring paused activity to front and deliver data to topmost instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

**App Background**

Music player app with ongoing notification

**Goal**

On notification tap, I must:

1. Bring whatever activity the user was last on to front
2. Show the full screen music player which is part of each activity's layout
3. NEVER create new tasks, so that means clicking on notif or launcher icon brings up the same task
4. Determine where intent came from (launcher or notif) and act accordingly (notif pops up full screen player, launcher just resumes current task

**Implementation so far**
So yeah, to do this, I have a single instance activity called LauncherActivity. All this does is call LoginActivity (I can't set LoginActivity to singleinstance because of Facebook SDK), then LoginActivity calls MainActivity after log in (or directly calls it and finishes itself if already logged in).

Now in my service, I have a pending intent set to launch launcher activity with action set to main, and category set to launcher (the same intent format that launcher uses):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyMainActivity.class);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

Now my question is, how do send data to the topmost activity? How will that activity know that it's being launched via the notif and not the launcher icon?

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the notification, add an "extra" to indicate that the `Intent` came from the notification:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyMainActivity.class);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
startActivity(i);
```

In `MyMainActivity.onNewIntent()` and `MyMainActivity.onCreate()` you can check if you've been launched from the notification like this:

```
if (intent.hasExtra("fromNotification")) {
    // Have been launched from the Notification here
}
```

in `onCreate()` you'll need to use `getIntent()` instead of just `intent`.

Comment: Hi yeah, sorry for the late reply. Sure this works for sending the intent to that specific activity, but waht if I want it delivered to the TOPMOST activity? Because main activity can open up other activities, and ideally I want to return the user to what he was doing previously, not forcing him to go to the main activity screen.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand all of your requirements. In this case, it might be better if your `Notification` send a broadcast `Intent` instead of starting an `Activity`. The broadcast `Intent` could then set a flag in a static variable that indicates it is being launched from a `Notification` and then start your launch activity. All your activities should then check this static variable in their `onResume()` method to determine how the app was (re)launched.